# VBA error : Invalid enumeration type

Tags: excel, vba

The following is a VBA function to copy a chart from a sheet in excel and paste it in powerpoint. However, this codes gives an error "**Invalid enumeration type**".
The error is in the line PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide.
Kindly help.

```
  Public Function copy_chart1(sheet, slide, group_name, ht, wdt, lf, tp)


Dim PPApp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim PPSlide As Object

Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")


Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (slide)

Worksheets(sheet).Activate

ActiveSheet.Shapes(group_name).CopyPicture


Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
With PPSlide
' paste and select the chart picture
.Shapes.Paste.Select

    With PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Height = ht
        .Width = wdt
        .Left = lf
        .Top = tp
    End With
End With


' Clean up
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PPApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Have you referenced the PowerPoint object library? Do you have `Option Explicit` in the beginning of the module?

Comment: Why the `GetObject` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are `Late Binding`, you need to replace all your PPt constants with its numeric value.

```
PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = 1 '~~> equivalent of ppViewSlide
```